# Is it possible to play two Steam games at once on the same computer/account?

Tags: steam

I want to play Garry's Mod and Team Fortress 2 at the same time so when I get bored of one I can easily alt tab to the other and when I'm needed back on the RP sever I like to join I can go back then as well.

Answer (score 18):

Steam doesn't have such limitation, but you can't play two [games that use Source Engine](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=16) at the same time.

Comment: Can you explain why we can't play two source games at the same time ?

Comment: Because when you try it complains that you can't (e.g. Portal 2 and Titanfall)

Comment: This limitation may have existed six years ago, but we just tested it and, as of 2018, it's perfectly possible to have two very similar games open at once.

Comment: @rosuav I just tried it, and it complained. Now what?

Comment: @Edward Which two games, and what was the complaint? I've had multiple Source games running simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should be able to just alt-tab out of one game and open the other.  This is a bit resource-intensive, though, so you may suffer some performance loss if you don't have a pretty powerful computer.

Comment: dual monitors? better than alt-tabbing if you do have the option.

Comment: @Enigma - Possibly worse, if you're having to hold all rendering content in VRAM / RAM, and can't page any out - not to mention rendering everything on both screens. I mean, it'll depend on the game, sure, but I don't think you can definitively say that it's the lighter option.

Comment: Yeah I meant better in terms of human effort. On most accounts it would be more effort from the PC.

Answer (score 2):

Steam does not limit how many games you can run at once, however, you can only run one source based game at once. This is a limitation of the engine, not Steam.

Comment: Could you add a source for that? No pun intended.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this with Garry's Mod and TF2 specifically (I don't own the former), but there is typically no such restriction.  In fact, earlier today, I accidentally launched two copies of DEFCON at once with Spiral Knights updating in the background!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming that both (or all but one) of the games you want to run simultaneously are reasonably gracious about being switched out of context. But that's an issue with the games in question, not Steam.

Steam's only limitation in the mix is that it will only *start* one game at a time; as soon as the "preparing to launch XXXXX" dialog vanishes Steam hands over control to the game itself and you can start a second.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, only if it's not two Source games.  But, many non-source games can be opened together (and you can have ONE source game and another non-source game).  Steam doesn't really care, it mostly depends on the games.  But don't try to open two really memory-destroying games at once.  Unless you're using a supercomputer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-multirun` in the launch options (in Steam, right-click game icon then click Properties and look at the bottom of the window). It worked for me with Garrysmod and Left 4 Dead 2.

Comment: Launch options is definitely specific to each game.

Comment: No they are the same for all Source Engine games.

Comment: that's entirely up to the developers to do that. They decided to have the same launch options right now. Nothing stops them from being disabled / changed in the future, and it definitely won't work for non- source engine games.

Comment: Read other comments, the problem is not about Steam, there is no problem running multiple games from Steam at the same time, except when they are Source games, an error appears if there is already a Source game running. Using the launch option as I suggested, which is common to all Source games using at least Source Engine 2013, allows to run multiple Source games at the same time. See https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options